# Why does my FF addon have trouble making screendumps of iframes with Flash animations in them?

Tags: javascript, flash, iframe, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have developed a Firefox addon (using the FF Addon SDK) that creates an image of the browser window and prints it to PDF.

So far it is working well, except for one case: if a page has an iframe on it that shows a Flash animation, the PDF just shows a black box where the iframe is supposed to be.

It works OK with iframes with content that's not Flash. It also works OK with Flash that's not in an iframe. It's just the combination that's causing a problem and I have absolutely no idea why.

This is how I create the image:

```
ctx.clearRect( 0 , 0 , canvas.width, canvas.height );
ctx.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
ctx.fillRect(0 , 0 , canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.drawWindow(window, x, y, w, h, "rgb(255, 255, 255)");  
var giantPic = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

giantPic is then chopped into smaller pics that fit on a page.

I'm sorry if this has been asked before. I must admit I have some trouble googling this problem, as I don't really understand what I am looking for.

Comment: Very interesting, I didn't know the quirk about flash in iframes were not being caught. I'm looking forward to seeing the solutions here.